# Valid Date Time conversion from String

Tags: c#

I keep getting the error of "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0." but I am unsure as the reason why.

```
                //Date and Age
            String months = Convert.ToString(txtMonth);
            String days = Convert.ToString(txtDay);
            String year = Convert.ToString(txtYear);
            String DOB = days + " " + months + " " + year;

            int age = AgeCalc(DOB);

  //Age Function
    private int AgeCalc(string date)
    {
        DateTime DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
        DateTime Year = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan span = Year - DOB;
        DateTime Age = DateTime.MinValue.AddDays(span.Days);
        return Age.Year - 1;
    }

//Separate Box
            MessageBox.Show("First Name:" + fName + "\nLast Name:" + lName + "\nGender:" + gender + "\nAge:" +
                age + "\nHeight (in inches):" + height + "\nWeight (lbs):" + weight + "\nMax Heart Rate:" + heartRate +
                "\nTarget Heart Rate:" + targetRate + "\nBMI:" + BMI, "Result");
```

More code provided on request.

Comment: So DOB (the string) might be `"10152020"`, and you expect that to be considered a valid date?

Comment: What is the type of the `txtXXXX` objects? Are they TextBoxes? Because if so, you should be using `txtXXXX.Text` instead of `Convert.ToString()`.

Comment: @ScottHunter I was messing with the code and that was the last iteration I used to see if it would work.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I changed it to txtXXXX.Text and got the same error.

Comment: Please show the declarations and value setting for `txtMonth` `txtDay` & `txtYear`. This is not an MVCE. For example, if txtMonth is actually a textbox and not a value that should be converted to string, e.g. an `int`, there's your problem right there.

Comment: @DeanOC I added my calls for the program. They are all their own textboxes that take in an integer. I have attempted to use ToInt32 as well when setting them to int and not strings.

Comment: Still not [mcve]. Ideally the question should be able to be copied and pasted into an environment so that it can be tested and eventually modified. Please, don't force us make guesses about data types or data values you need tested or validated. Specifically in the example you provided we have no idea what you expect for "txtYear" or "txtMonth"....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to detect if the user entered the wrong value try this

```
string[] formats = { "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd/M/yyyy", "d/M/yyyy", "d/MM/yyyy","dd/MM/yy", "dd/M/yy", "d/M/yy", "d/MM/yy"};
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime DOB))
{
    // DOB variable is ready to use
    Label1.Text = DOB.ToShortDateString();
} else {
    //error handling goes here
    Label1.Text = "ERROR: Invalid value";
}
```

DOB.ToShortDateString() will convert back into a string.

Comment: Whenever anyone feels the need to "downvote" a provided solution, that persons should provide a comment explaining the reason(s) why they believe the solution warrants a "downvote". The user who posted this solution appears to be new to SO. They have provided a solution that works properly and the code will produce a valid `DataTime` when the data entered does indeed match the "formats" provided. I see nothing wrong with the solution. In fact, I believe it to be a much better pattern than just assuming the data would produce a valid `DateTime`. +1

Comment: I would suggest you provide a bit more information along with the solution you provided. Perhaps even provide values and code that can be copy and pasted in order for it to be tested.

Comment: This is the safe way to do it. I always prefer using `TryParse` methods, even when it does lead to more code.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you only allow users to input correct value (valid integer). You can use this

```
new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(txtYear), Convert.ToInt32(txtMonth), Convert.ToInt32(txtDay));
```

Comment: It is giving me a different error now that says: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' to type 'System.IConvertible'."

Comment: then you need to put txtYear.Value instead of txtYear

Comment: It isn't allowing me to do that anywhere where I have txtYear.

Comment: Hover over `txtYear` and `txtMonth` and `txtDay` to see their types @SleepingPanda. What are they?

Comment: It just tells me that it is a textbox, no type. (field) TextBox BMI_Calc.txtXXXX

Comment: Use `txtYear.Text` then.